# Get less variables list using less.js

Tags: javascript, css, variables, less

I'm using client-side less.js. Is there a way to get all variables from my less file. I know how to modify variables:

```
less.modifyVars({
  "@var": "#fff"
});
```

But I want to get all of them, like (don't work):

```
var variables = less.getVars();
```

Comment: well all variables start with `@` don't know if less offers something, but you can pretty much execute a regular expression and find all variables

Comment: Find where? I need to load them to variable for example

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand why this maybe not ideal but still perfectly valid question was put on hold. Does at least one of close-voters have an idea of what Less is? I'm voting for re-opening.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Possibly something to do with this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311929/congrats-on-1m-javascript-questions?cb=1#comment280701_311929).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is going to be an unconventional answer as it seems that this data isn't publicly exposed as part of the browser facing API.

---

**tl;dr**

- Save a local copy of the `less.js` file.
- Add this function definition somewhere

  ```
  function exposeVars(root) {
       var r=root._variables,n=Object.keys(r),m={}
       for(var k of n){m[k]=r[k].value}
           less.variables = m;
  }
  ```
- Add the following call `exposeVars(evaldRoot)` just before `return result` on line ~2556.
- Now `less.variables` contains all the variables from your file.

**Disclaimer**: Doing this is not a good idea! It's fine if you're just playing around, debugging or testing something, but don't depend on this hack for anything serious!

---

The basic aim here was to find the point in the source where the `.less` files are turned into abstract syntax trees (or some other formal structure).

Jumping straight into the source, I found a `ParseTree` class. It's a reasonable assumption to guess that it will contain the result of parsing the less file.

I wrote a quick test file and added it to the browser with the appropriate tag. It looks like this:

```
@myvar: red;
@othervar: 12px;

body {
  padding: @othervar;
  background: @myvar;
}
```

I've downloaded a local copy of [less.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.3/less.js) and added a breakpoint added to line 2556.

I had a poke around in the local scope to see what was available and found the variables in an object called `evaldRoot`.

```
evaldRoot = {
  _variables: {
    @myvar: {
      name: '@myvar',
      value: Color
    },
    @othervar: {
      name: '@othervar',
      value: Dimension
    }
  }
}
```

Next job was to work out where this data goes. It seems like the `evaldRoot` variable is used to generate the resulting CSS (which would make sense, as it contains information such as variables).

```
if (options.sourceMap) {
  sourceMapBuilder = new SourceMapBuilder(options.sourceMap);
  result.css = sourceMapBuilder.toCSS(evaldRoot, toCSSOptions, this.imports);
} else {
  result.css = evaldRoot.toCSS(toCSSOptions);
}
```

Whatever happens, the variables goes out of scope after it is used to generate a string of CSS as `result.css`.

To expose of these variables, the script needs a small modification. You'll have to expose the variables publicly somehow. Here's an example of doing that.

```
function exposeVars(root) {
  var varNames = Object.keys(root._variables);

  var variables = varNames.reduce(function(varMap, varName) {
    varMap[varName] = root._variables[varName].value;
  }, {});

  less.variables = variables;
}
```

This can be added just before the return statement with the breakpoint.

```
exposeVars(evaldRoot);
return result;
```

Now the variables will be available in a `name: value` object on the global `less` object.

[image]

You could even modify the expose function to return the variables from a call to `less.getVars()`. Just like your initial suggestion.

```
function exposeVars(root) {
  // ...
  less.getVars = function() {
    return variables;
  };
}
```